# Apache - 413 (Request Entity Too Large)

Tags: php, ajax, apache, file, dreamhost

I was trying to upload an image (673KB), but I was getting this error:

```
POST http://www.example.com/crop-image 413 (Request Entity Too Large)
```

I know my ajax and php code are correct since it is working on Xampp (same image can be uploaded), but once I moved to Dreamhost, certain files could not be uploaded due this error.

I also tried uploading same size png file (600K) which worked fine. Also smaller JPG (~50K) are also working.

I googled the error and tried updating php.ini:

```
 max_input_time = 24000
 max_execution_time = 24000
 upload_max_filesize = 12000M
 post_max_size = 24000M
 memory_limit = 12000M
```

I also added this line in the beginning of `.htaccess` file:

```
LimitRequestBody 104857600

...
```

But I am still getting same error... Could I be missing something?

Comment: Since it works for png, check all htaccess files and all of the files in the apache config directory for rules regarding jpg files.

Comment: After some testing found out that smaller resolution jpg are uploaded. 673KB is too big and 50KB is working fine.

Comment: Check the settings in your phprc file (php.ini)